# I need a custom Excel Formula for 5 different situations

Tags: excel

```
IF A2>=25 {

   IF B2>=17 then print("Bad Product")
   IF B2<17  then print("FALSE")

} ELSE IF A2<25 {

   IF B2>=6 then print("Bad Product")
   IF B2<6  then print("FALSE")

} else print "Withous Value"
```

Comment: Not sure which language this should be. But if you are looking for an Excel formula equivalent then this might work: `=IF(A2>=25, IF(B2>=17, "Bad Product"), IF(B2>=6,"Bad Product"))`. Note, that I eliminated `False` as this is the default when an `IF` isn't getting to `True`. Also, I wasn't able to understand the final `else` in your post as `A2>=25` and `A2<15` have already been dealt. So, you might want to elaborate what that should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(A2 >= 25, IF(B2 >=17, "Bad Product", "FALSE"), IF(A2 < 25, IF(B2 >= 6, "Bad Product", "FALSE"), "Withous Value"))
```

Comment: Are you aware that `Withous Value` can never be reached in your formula and is (as such) obsolete?

Comment: I am aware of the fact, but the question specifically requests for that case

Comment: @Ralph, what if A2 is imaginary?

Comment: @J.Chomel You can play around with `IMAGINARY()` and `COMPLEX()` as much as you want for `A2` and still won't be able to generate a case where `Without Value` is shown. In short: I dare you to prove me wrong and give me / us any value (or formula) for `A2` which will (with the above formula) default to `Without Value`.

Comment: @Ralph, just joking, pal! :) I can see unicorns right in front of me.